# SQL Server : update a value within the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to use an update command for the table below. What I want to do is to update the `answer` column based on the `reference` column: 2nd and 3rd answers should be A because their reference is 1 and answer of the 1st row is A, similarly 5 and 6 should be X.

Sample data:

```
id    answer  ref
-------------------
1       A      1
2       B      1
3       C      1
4       x      4
5       y      4
6       z      4
```

Comment: which database you are using???

Comment: microsoft sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update a
set a.answer = b.answer
from tablename a, tablename b
where a.ref = b.id
```

edit:
adding this also may be better;

```
and a.ref <> a.id
```

Answer (score 1):

update table1 t1 set answer = t2.answer from table1 t2 where t1.ref = t2.id;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `case` statement

```
UPDATE sample_data
SET answer = ref
WHERE CASE 
      WHEN ref = 1
      THEN answer = 'A' 
      ELSE
      WHEN REF = 4
      THEN ANSWER = 'x'
END as available
```

Comment: I have more than 4000 records, that's why I did not use case statement. Serif Emek s solution worked. thank you for your contribution anyways.